# Concatenate text with knitr

Tags: r, knitr

Using knitr, I want to print the results of several functions for some variable, e.g.

```
There were x1 (a=\`r a(x1)\`; b=\`r b(x1)\`) and x2 (a=\`r a(x2)\`; b=\`r b(x2)\`)
```

Since I don't like to repeat this for every variable, I wrote a function to generate the string:

```
foo <- function(x) paste('a = ',a(x), '; b = ', b(x))
```

Now I can write `` There were x1 (`r foo(x1)`) and x2 (`r foo(x2)`) ``.

It works, but doesn't use `options('digits')`, so it prints 15 digits. `cat()` uses `options('digits')`, but apprently [using cat is discouraged](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/output/) and doesn't output anything when using inline code.

Is there an alternative to `paste()` that formats numbers with `options('digits') and creates output in inline chunks?

Answer (score 3):

"Using of cat discouraged": this is a misunderstanding. Yihui warns against using `cat` to output messages. If you want to created clean output, you often must use cat. Try the following in your chunk:

```
options(digits=2)
x1 = 2.304302
# chunk output
x1 # Ugly, [1]
cat(x1,"\n") # Must use cat here, to avoid the [1] printed
```

Re you main question: No chance here without explicit formating in your `foo` function, probably best with `sprintf`. `Options` only applies in the inline numeric code, not to strings as supplied by your function `foo`. `knitr` does not interfere with the function of `paste`, and paste does not honor `options`.

```
x2 = 4.489324802    
options(digits=2)
paste(x2)
```

"4.489324802"

Comment: Nice to hear that I can use cat without a bad conscience. However, cat doesn't print anything when used in inline code, e.g. `Example: \`r cat(2.50,' ; ',3.131,' ; ',4.987)\``

Comment: Yes, that point was correct (and it is documented somewhere). cat is good for in-chunk code.

Comment: @tstenner `cat()` returns `NULL`, so you get nothing. I think you have to use one explicit formatting function such as `format[C]()`, `sprintf()` or `round()` here, e.g. `sprintf('%.02f', x)` or `round(x, getOption('digits'))`

Answer (score 0):

Probably `format(x, ...)` would work for this. (not tested)

Comment: It should work, but it accepts only one argument, so I'd have to write something like `paste('a = ',format(a(x),...),...)`

Comment: That's where sprintf is better, even if the syntax is a bit strange for non C-afficionados